# Normalized Object and array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "delta1"
    },
    "property_data": [
      {
        "ser_name": "Insights",
        "ser_value": "10000"
      },
      {
        "ser_name": "plans",
        "ser_value": "50000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Explanation**  : `property_data` is an array. `data` is an object. Need to transform Array into an object, but the problem is if I do `$unwind` on `property_data` I get multiple times `data` objects, which I needed only once. I want to convert my data structure, into multiple documents but `data` should not be repeated again and again

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "property_data": {
     "id": "123",
      "name": "delta1"
    }
  },
  {
    "property_data": {
      "ser_name": "Insights",
      "ser_value": "10000"
    }
  },
  {
    "property_data": {
      "ser_name": "plans",
      "ser_value": "50000"
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with some basic structure manipulation, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      property_data: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$property_data",
          [
            "$data"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$property_data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        property_data: "$property_data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sCvYjn1edkL)